# Can infinite joins/meets be viewed as special cases of a limit with respect to some topology?

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $L$ denote a complete lattice. Is there a topology on $L$ such that infinite joins and meets can be viewed as a special kind of "limit"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any partially ordered set has a topology generated by the open intervals $(a, b) = \{ c : a < b < c \}$ and half-open intervals $(a, \infty) = \{ c : a < c \}, (-\infty, a) = \{ c : c < a \}$. Infinite suprema and infima are limits with respect to this topology. (I would call this the *order topology* except that this term appears to be reserved for the special case of totally ordered sets for reasons I don't understand.)

But there is an even better way to understand infinite joins and meets that also uses the word "limit"! Namely, they are [categorical (co)limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(category_theory)), thinking of a partially ordered set as a category where $a \le b$ means that there is a unique arrow from $a$ to $b$.